How can I create a geospatial heat map in Python using coordinates?
If I have a very large list of coordinates, how would I be able to create a geospatial heat map of these using Python. There are no values associated with each coordinate - they are just locations and each is equal. The number of locations/coordinates would probably be in the tens to hundreds of thousands.
Since many of the coordinates are accurate to 6 decimal places, I was thinking one option would be to round to 3 decimal places and use the frequencies as "heat levels".
Thanks for any help.
The only examples of this I have seen were either:

Ones where the locations have different values. That is not what I'm going for with this heatmap.

Ones where values are repeated. While some of the coordinates may be repeated, many are accurate to 5-6 decimal places. The number of duplicate coordinates without rounding will be minimal.



I would use python to generate a json payload of coords and pass that to an html page that uses Echarts to render... https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=heatmap-bmap
